# How to make a Button inside a ListView ItemTemplate trigger SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

How to fire the `SelectionChanged` event if a ListViewItem DataTemplate Button is clicked?

At present `SelectionChanged` only fires if we click a ListViewItem keeping the mouse outside of the Button.

As the Button is inside of the ListViewItem we want it to first trigger `SelectionChanged`  and then the `Click` event handler of the button.

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PDFsOC, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedPDF, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.lv_pdfs_SelectionChanged}">

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel >

            <Button Click="btn_preview_front_pdf"   <<<< SelectionChanged does not fire >>>>
                Content="Preview Front PDF" />          

            <Button Margin="10 0 0 0"
                Click="btn_preview_back_pdf"        <<<< SelectionChanged does not fire >>>>
                Content="Preview Back PDF"
                IsEnabled="{Binding HasBack, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Click` event will indeed be handled first but you could explicitly select the parent `ListViewItem` the first thing you do in this event handler by setting the `SelectedItem` of the control (or the `SelectedPDF` property of the view model) to the `DataContext` of the clicked button:

```
private void btn_preview_front_pdf(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectListViewItem(sender); // this will select the item and fire the SelectionChanged event
    
    // your current code here...
}

private void SelectListViewItem(object sender)
{
    FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    listView.SelectedItem = fe.DataContext;
}
```